# Upload File with angularJs passing additional parametres

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, asp.net-web-api2

I must do an upload of some images with Angularjs... The upload must be done in a custom folder, depending on the client is doing the upload... The folder could not exists, so, if it does not, I must create it...
I am doing the upload using this [module](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) ...
Here the controller that receive the file:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult UploadFile()
{
    var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0 ?
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0] : null;

    ...

    return Ok();
}
```

It works, but I cannot pass parameters to the method.. or perhaps I am not able... I would like something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult UploadFile(MyModel parameters)
{
    var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0 ?
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0] : null;

    ...

    return Ok();
}
```

Where MyModel, for example, is something like:

```
public class MyModel
{
     public string folderName ....;
     ...

     public List<File> FilesToUpload ...;
}
```

Perhaps the module I am using is complicating my life, so I can remove it with no problem... Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to following link for detailed information uploading file and sending json data in a single call

"http://shazwazza.com/post/uploading-files-and-json-data-in-the-same-request-with-angular-js/"